# Почему неправильно работает программа, рекуррентно высчитывающая значение синуса через ряд Тейлора?

Tags: c, рекуррентность

Условие задачи:"Необходимо написать программу, в которой вводятся значения n и x и выводится сумма ряда с указанной точностью n, а также сумма ряда с максимально возможной точностью"
Например, для значения x = 32.2 не выводится заданная точность, а максимальная печатается. Может быть есть ошибки, которые я не могу увидеть? Объясните, пожалуйста. Заранее благодарен!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

// Определение значения эпсилон
#define LDBL_EPSILON pow(2,-63)

// Функция для вычисления максимально возможной точности через эпсилон
int max_accuracy(long double x, long double n, long double e)
{
    int i;
    long double memory = x;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        memory *= -x * x / ((2 * i + 2) * (2 * i + 3));
        // Проверяем условие окончания итераций
        if (fabsl(memory) <= e)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

long double max_sum(long double x, long double n, long double e)
{
    int i;
    long double sum_i = x;
    long double memory = x;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        memory *= -x * x / ((2 * i + 2) * (2 * i + 3));
        sum_i += memory;
        // Проверяем условие окончания итераций
        if (fabsl(memory) <= e)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return sum_i;
}

int main()
{
    long double n, x, sum, term = 0;
    printf("input n:");
    scanf_s("%Lf", &n);
    printf("input x:");
    scanf_s("%Lf", &x);
    // Определение значения эпсилон
    long double e = LDBL_EPSILON;
    int maxN = max_accuracy(x, n, e); // Вычисление максимально возможной точности
    // Итерации для вычисления синуса с помощью формулы Тейлора
    sum = x;
    long double member = x;
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxN; i++) {
        member *= (-x * x / ((2 * i + 2) * (2 * i + 3)));
        sum += member;
        if (i == n) {
            printf("given accuracy: %.15lf\n", sum);
        }
    }
    printf("sin max accuracy: %.15lf\n", max_sum(x,n,e));
    printf("sin math.h: %.15lf", sinl(x));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сформулируйте точное условие задания. А то у вас код какой-то странный...

Comment: Судя по _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS Вы используете MSC, но у MSC по умолчанию long double == double, соответственно, LDBL_EPSILON будет гораздо больше.

Comment: добавил условие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании функции `int max_accuracy(long double x, long double n, long double e)` вы скопировали код из другой `long double max_sum(long double x, long double n, long double e)` и совершили типичную ошибку бездумного копирования кода.
Цикл должен заканчиваться до условия, приближения к заданной точности, а **не** количеству слагаемых.
Нужно удалить лишний аргумент `n`.

```c
int max_accuracy(long double x, /* long double n,*/ long double e)
{
    int i;
    long double memory = x;
    for (i = 0; /*i < n*/ ; i++)
    {
        memory *= -x * x / ((2 * i + 2) * (2 * i + 3));
        // Проверяем условие окончания итераций
        if (fabsl(memory) <= e)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

*И попутно нужно исправить в функциях `printf` заменой `"%lf"` на `"%Lf"`*

Comment: Всё равно не работает. Вывод в консоли такой:
input n:234
input x:32.2
sin max accuracy: 0.706347419729202
sin math.h: 0.706169457180334

Comment: Ну, как я понял, при некоторых n мы достигаем максимума раньше чем заданной точности, поэтому выводится только максимальное значение. Так, например, для n = 40 и x = 32.2 у нас выводится и заданная точность, и максимально возможная точность.

Answer (score 0):

В справочниках форумы Тейлора представлены в математическом виде, это когда количество цифр после запятой бесконечно. Но в реальности переменные имеют фиксированную точность. Для того чтобы не накапливать ошибку, нужно складывать от меньшего к большему. Буквально сохранять результаты в массив, и только потом вычислять сумму. Кроме того есть минимальный порог для входного параметра, ниже нельзя - получится бесконечность.